# Has jQuery Template no conditionals?

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, template-engine, jquery-templates

I'm watching a course (2014) about jQuery Template.

One sentence troubled me:
from text

> The nice thing about jQuery Template is that it's a plug in for
>   jQuery. And it leverages existing jQuery syntax. And many websites
>   already use jQuery. So chances are, you're already familiar with how
>   to load and use this particular plugin. It's used for simple
>   templating. **There are no conditionals or logic in jQuery Template.**

But jQuery Template has {{if}}, {{else}}. So jQuery Template **has conditionals**. Am I right?)
Or don't I misunderstand author? Or is it serious author mistake?

I try to find documentation

[jquery-template](https://github.com/codepb/jquery-template) - is it old version? I didn't find *if* statements

[jquery-tmpl](https://github.com/borismoore/jquery-tmpl) - Is it new version? readme.md describes

> {each}}, {{if}}, {{else}}, {{html}}, {{tmpl}} and {{wrap}}

Answer (score 0):

For context on jQuery Templates, see the info on the [jquery-templates](/questions/tagged/jquery-templates) tag: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-templates/info.

You will see that the original official jQuery templates is this one [jquery-tmpl](https://github.com/borismoore/jquery-tmpl). It does support conditionals. The ongoing next-generation version of jQuery templates is [jsrender](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender) - which actually has better separation of code, markup and logic, (and better separation from the DOM) - and provides more powerful logic support than jQuery Templates did.

The other link you give, to [jquery-template](https://github.com/codepb/jquery-template) is a completely different templating approach, that recently chose to use 'jquery-templates' for its github project name, although it is in fact quite unrelated to the official (and much used) jQuery Templates.

Comment: OK. Thanks, BorisMoore. So, it's serious author mistake: jQuery Template HAS conditionals AND logic. Or rather simple conditionals (if/else) and logic (each).